# When I encapulate a group of DependencyProperties into a DependencyObject, will property changes automatically be forwarded to UserControl?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, dependencyobject

I created a WPF UserControl with a number of `DependencyProperty` custom properties, which all affect OnMeasure and call `PropertyChangedCallback`, e.g.:

```cs
private static readonly DependencyProperty ArrowStrokeThicknessProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ArrowStrokeThickness", typeof(double), typeof(ProjectListTreePanel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(2d, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure, PropertyChangedCallback), ValidateArrowStrokeThickness);
```

I'd rather put all these properties into a separate `DependencyObject`:

```cs
internal class MyArrowProperties : DependencyObject
{
  private static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeThicknessProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("StrokeThickness", typeof(double), typeof(MyArrowProperties), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(2d, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure, PropertyChangedCallback), ValidateStrokeThickness);
  ...
}
```

... and have that `DependencyObject` become a `DependencyProperty` of my `UserControl`:

```cs
public partial class ProjectListTreePanel : UserControl
{
  private static readonly DependencyProperty ArrowProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Arrow", typeof(MyArrowProperties), typeof(ProjectListTreePanel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure, PropertyChangedCallback));
```

Will changes to the properties of the `MyArrowProperties` `DependencyObject` be automatically forwarded to the containing `ProjectListTreePanel` `UserControl`, so `MeasureOverride` is getting called on the `ProjectListTreePanel` `UserControl`, when, for instance, I update

```cs
MyProjectListTreePanel.Arrow.StrokeThickness = 2
```

?

Or what do I need to do to have changes of encapsulated properties be forwarded to outer containers?

#### Similarity

The problem described here is similar to the `Thickness` struct. The `Thickness` struct is a collection of four distinct values. When any of these values changes, the `Thickness` struct raises an `OnPropertyChanged` event.

Comment: Probably not, but you could simply try it. Besides that, controls typically have many properties, so where is the point of your idea?

Comment: I have a deep hierarchy of controls all sharing the same set of properties. I'd like to refrain from writing too much boiler plate code. On the other hand, I'm asking for a general rule of thumb. I was expecting this wouldn't work automatically. So, what's the suggested approach? Firing `OnPropertyChanged` for all the enclosed properties?